# How to make program open multiple windows? Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

My program is getting the file from a directory and it starts some processing on that file. If that processing is not done well, the program pops up a window constructed in another program.

My problem is that if one window is open, and the program wants to open one extra window after an extra file has been added to the directory and processed, it is unable to do this.

Minimal version of the sort of code I've written:

```
while (true) {
    file f = getnewfile();
    if (f==new) {
        processing();
        if (processing == ntgood) {
             window.setVisible(true);
        } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reword your question to include a question? Currently it's a statement.

Comment: If I understand your question, the application is not opening a new window. It only opens one ? if that is the case you only have one window and you set the Visibility to true. you should be creating the window in the loop if you want multiple windows.

Comment: thats the right problem kenneth. Yes i am creating the window in the while - loop, but yet it only opens one window if the window from before is stil open. The window that is showing is the window from before. Not both, which is my goal

Comment: can you post some code from the window class? I'm curious to see what options the user is presented with and how you're working that

Comment: Its a lot of codes, but its simply text field that  i being typed with info, and after pressing a button, the info is written into a table in  a DB in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JOptionPane to display a small message to the user. The user may then close window at his or her leisure.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File X parsed");
```

Comment: maybe I didnt explain, but in the window its a couple of commands that has to be performed by the admin. Thats why I can not use MessageDialog

Comment: Gotchya. Is the window blocking? Does it stop the program thread and wait for user input?

Comment: No,the window is not blocking. The program runs perfect outside. But when the window no.2 tries to open, it doesn't start in a new window, but the old one is "blinking" like a new window. Ive tried with eventQueue.invokelater but it did not do the work

Answer (score 0):

You can open multiple windows as follows:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class WindowOpener {

    private static final int WINDOW_COUNT = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < WINDOW_COUNT; i++) {
                    JFrame f = new JFrame();
                    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    f.setSize(150, 250);
                    f.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```